# How to specify the order of items in ReactCSSTransitionGroup?

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

Is it possible to specify the order of items in a `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`?

Consider a list of items which their order is important. If you want to show one item and hide its adjacent with one action, `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` confuses their order. Take a look the following fiddle, the items are supposed to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

http://jsfiddle.net/mehranziadloo/kb3gN/15519/

Is it possible to tell `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` (or `ReactTransitionGroup`) the sequence of items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ReactCSSTransitionGroup just animates changes in DOM, it doesn't care about order. Your state changes from odd to even numbers, there is no moment when it contains sorted array with all the numbers. You can work around it by modifying state in different way, temporary saving old items for animation purposes, something like that:

```
switch: function() {
  var newItems;
  if (this.state.items[0] % 2 !== 1) {
    newItems = [1, 3, 5];
  }
  else {
    newItems = [2, 4];
  }
  this.setState({
    items: newItems,
    previousItems: this.state.items
  }, function() {
    this.setState({
      previousItems: []
    })
  });
}
```

After that, you need to modify your render method:

```
render: function() {
  var currentItems = this.state.items.concat(this.state.previousItems).sort();
  var items = currentItems.map(function(item, i) {
    return (
      <div key={item}>
        {item}
      </div>
    );
  }.bind(this));
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.switch}>Switch</button>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={1000} transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}>
        {items}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ny5La5ky/